# How to make GET request to Unsplash run on every page refresh?

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I'm trying to get a random background from Unsplash on every page refresh but I only get a new background when I restart the server. I'm not sure if this is normal behavior or if there's something that I could do to trigger the GET request on page refresh. Thank you all in advance!

Axios GET request to Unsplash API

```
const axios = require('axios');
const env = require("dotenv");

let pictureResult = [];

let picture = axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random', {
           params: { query: 'motivational',
                     orientation: 'landscape'
                   },
           headers: {
             Authorization:
             'Client-ID ' + process.env.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY
           }
}).then(function(response){
  if(response){
    pictureResult.push(response.data.urls.full);
    console.log(pictureResult);
  } else {
    console.log("Success!");
  }
});


module.exports = pictureResult;
```

server.js

```
const unsplashPic = require('./app/ext-api/unsplash/unsplash.js');
const ejs = require('ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(unsplashPic);
  res.render('pages/index', { picture: unsplashPic });
});
```

Comment: nowhere are you calling the random image endpoint on page refresh. you call it once, when the app runs for the first time, so it happens only once.

Comment: Hello Jay,
I thought that whenever I refresh the page it would trigger a new GET request, good to know that now XD.
Thank you for the quick response.